# csh idioms to check for environment variable existence?

Tags: environment-variables, csh

I've got a few csh scripts where I need to check that certain environment variables are set before I start doing stuff, so I do this sort of thing:

```
if ! $?STATE then
    echo "Need to set STATE"
    exit 1
endif

if ! $?DEST then
    echo "Need to set DEST"
    exit 1
endif
```

which is a lot of typing. Is there a more elegant idiom for checking whether or not an environment variable is already set?

Notes:

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307503/whats-the-best-way-to-check-that-environment-variables-are-set-in-unix-shellscri) is quite similar, but specifically asks about solutions in bash.
- I'm not looking for people to advise me to stay away from csh because it's cursed, scary, or bash is better.  I'm specifically interested in a more elegant solution than what I'm using now.

Comment: [This newer, similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343392/how-to-check-if-an-environment-variable-is-either-unset-or-set-to-the-empty-stri) also show how to check in an expression context where if/else/endif is not possible

Answer (score 22):

I think the way you're doing it (an `if` statement with a condition using the `$?VAR` syntax, which evaluates to 1 if the variable is set, and 0 otherwise) is probably the most idiomatic `csh` construct that does what you want.

Answer (score -7):

Try the following:

```
[ -z STATE ] && echo "Need to set STATE"

[ ! -z DEST  ] && echo "Need to set STATE"
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to say here - you have two opposite pieces of logic printing the same message.

Comment: In any case this is not csh