# Meaning of $? (dollar question mark) in shell scripts

Tags: shell, scripting, special-characters

What does

```
echo $?
```

mean in shell programming?

Comment: exit status of last command

Comment: This answer is correct, but also note that [in CSH, `$?VARIABLE_NAME` has a different meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2336388/411282), for checking if a variable is set.

Answer (score 372, accepted):

This is the exit status of the last executed command.

For example the command `true` always returns a status of `0` and `false` always returns a status of `1`:

```
true
echo $? # echoes 0
false
echo $? # echoes 1
```

From the manual: (acessible by calling `man bash` in your shell)

> `?`            Expands to the exit status of the most recently  executed  foreground pipeline.

By convention an exit status of `0` means success, and non-zero return status means failure. Learn more about *exit statuses* [on wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Exit_status).

There are other special variables like this, as you can see on this online manual: https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters

Answer (score 35):

`$?` returns the exit value of the last executed command. `echo $?` prints that value on console. zero implies a successful execution while non-zero values are mapped to various reason for failure.

Hence when scripting; I tend to use the following syntax

```
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
 # do something
else
 # do something else
fi
```

The comparison is to be done on equals to `0` or not equals `0`.

** Update Based on the comment: Ideally, you should not use the above code block for comparison, refer to @tripleee comments and explanation.

Comment: No, this is an antipattern.  Anything which looks like `cmd; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then` should be refactored to `if cmd; then`.  The very *purpose* of `if` (and the other flow control statements in the shell) is to run a command and examine its exit status.

Comment: ```if cmd;``` may not be very readable is some conditions especially when cmd refers to another script.

Comment: This is even more wrong now. `[ 1 ]` and `[ 0 ]` are both true; `[` without an operator checks if the argument is a non-empty string.

Comment: Why would `externalscript; if [ $? -eq 0 ]` be more readable than `if externalscript`?

Comment: I'm about to do `vendor/bin/drush status bootstrap | grep -q $(vendor/bin/drush php-eval 'if (function_exists("t")) echo t("Successful");') &> /dev/null;`. If I had to put that in a single line `if [ ... ]` it would be terribly unreadable. I plan to store the output of that line to a variable so I can just say `if [ $drupal_installed -eq 0 ]` later.

Comment: See also [Why is testing `“$?”` to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Comment: @thirdender The proper solution to that is to encapsulate the complex test in a shell function.

Comment: I would say if there are only 0 and non-0, it's ok to check `if cmd`, if I need to act according to more than two cases, I need to check against, for example, 0 and 1 and 2.

Answer (score 17):

**echo $?** - Gives the EXIT STATUS of the *most recently executed command* . This EXIT STATUS would most probably be a number with ZERO implying **Success** and any NON-ZERO value indicating ***Failure***

**?**  - This is one special parameter/variable in bash.

**$?** - It gives the value stored in the variable "?".

Some similar special parameters in BASH are 1,2,*,# ( Normally seen in echo command as $1 ,$2 , $* , $# , etc., ) .

Answer (score 9):

It has the last status code (exit value) of a command.

Answer (score 8):

**Minimal POSIX C exit status example**

To understand `$?`, you must first understand the concept of process exit status which is defined [by POSIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780599/what-is-the-meaning-of-posix/31865755#31865755). In Linux:

- when a process calls the `exit` system call, the kernel stores the value passed to the system call (an `int`) even after the process dies.

  The exit system call is called by the `exit()` ANSI C function, and indirectly when you do `return` from `main`.
- the process that called the exiting child process (Bash), often with `fork` + `exec`, can retrieve the exit status of the child with the `wait` system call

Consider the Bash code:

```
$ false
$ echo $?
1
```

The C "equivalent" is:

false.c

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit */

int main(void) {
    exit(1);
}
```

bash.c

```
#include <unistd.h> /* execl */
#include <stdlib.h> /* fork */
#include <sys/wait.h> /* wait, WEXITSTATUS */
#include <stdio.h> /* printf */

int main(void) {
    if (fork() == 0) {
        /* Call false. */
        execl("./false", "./false", (char *)NULL);
    }
    int status;
    /* Wait for a child to finish. */
    wait(&status);
    /* Status encodes multiple fields,
     * we need WEXITSTATUS to get the exit status:
     * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659616/returning-exit-code-from-child
     **/
    printf("$? = %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
}
```

Compile and run:

```
g++ -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o bash bash.c
g++ -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o false false.c
./bash
```

Output:

```
$? = 1
```

In Bash, when you hit enter, a fork + exec + wait happens like above, and bash then sets `$?` to the exit status of the forked process.

Note: for built-in commands like `echo`, a process need not be spawned, and Bash just sets `$?` to 0 to simulate an external process.

**Standards and documentation**

POSIX 7 2.5.2 "Special Parameters" http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02 :

> ? Expands to the decimal exit status of the most recent pipeline (see Pipelines).

`man bash` "Special Parameters":

> The shell treats several parameters specially.  These parameters may only be referenced; assignment to them is not allowed. [...]
>
> ? Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.

ANSI C and POSIX then recommend that:

- `0` means the program was successful
- other values: the program failed somehow.

  The exact value could indicate the type of failure.

  ANSI C does not define the meaning of any vaues, and POSIX specifies  values larger than 125:  [What is the meaning of "POSIX"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780599/i-never-really-understood-what-is-posix/31865755#31865755)

**Bash uses exit status for `if`**

In Bash, we often use the exit status `$?` implicitly to control `if` statements as in:

```
if true; then
  :
fi
```

where `true` is a program that just returns 0.

The above is equivalent to:

```
true
result=$?
if [ $result = 0 ]; then
  :
fi
```

And in:

```
if [ 1 = 1 ]; then
  :
fi
```

`[` is just an program with a weird name (and Bash built-in that behaves like it), and `1 = 1 ]` its arguments, see also: [Difference between single and double square brackets in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542832/what-is-the-difference-between-single-and-double-square-brackets-in-bash/31366734#31366734)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters

```
?
Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.
```

Answer (score 3):

See [The Bash Manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html) under [3.4.2 Special Parameters](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters):

> ? - Expands to the exit status of the most recently executed foreground pipeline.

It is a little hard to find because it is not listed as `$?` (the variable name is "just" `?`). Also see the [exit status](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/bash.html#Exit-Status) section, of course ;-)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Outputs the result of the last executed unix command

```
0 implies true
1 implies false
```