# How can I detect if Docker for macOS is installed?

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-for-mac, docker-desktop

I have some makefiles where most of the stuff should run without configuration. These makefiles have used `docker-machine` in the past.

Is there a way to detect in Bash if the user is using **Docker Desktop for Mac** instead of `docker-machine`?

Comment: As noted in the official [getting started instructions](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/) it's no longer recommended to use `docker-machine` as it requires VirtualBox, as opposed to _Docker Desktop_ which uses the much faster **xhyve** and does not require VirtualBox to function. Consider refactoring your makefiles to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to check for the existence of the DOCKER environment variables:

- DOCKER_HOST
- DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME
- DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY
- DOCKER_CERT_PATH

All four of these are set when `eval $(docker-machine env)` is run and are required for use with docker-machine.

The beta does not require any of them being set and in fact requires you to unset them in order to function properly.

---

You can also do a check in the `docker info` command looking for "moby" (the name of the docker for mac VM):

```
docker info | grep -q moby && echo "Docker for mac beta" || echo "Not docker for mac beta"
```

This is going to be dependent on consistency in the `docker info` results, however.

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking about this. However, i would prefer a positive condition checking for the existing of "Docker for mac"

Comment: @JE42 I added another check for that, too, which is more of a positive.

Answer (score 5):

The cleanest way I found so far is:

```
[[ $(docker version --format "{{.Server.KernelVersion}}") == *-moby ]]
```

Comment: Slight update: on 18.03,  `KernelVersion` reports `4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs`, so one can check for `*-linuxkit-*` I guess.

Answer (score 2):

You can open the terminal and just type `docker info` and it will give you the details about the docker if it is installed on your mac.

If it says `command not found : docker` then it means you don't have docker installed on your mac.

Answer (score 1):

> These makefiles have used `docker-machine` in the past.

If possible stop using Machine. Recent Docker for Mac [installation instructions](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/) note Docker Toolbox but suggest it's *legacy* now. Consider refactoring your scripts to check for Docker Desktop instead:

```sh
if [[ -n "$(docker info --format '{{.OperatingSystem}}' | grep 'Docker Desktop')" ]]; then
    echo "Docker Desktop found. Skipping installation ..."
else
    echo "WARNING! Docker Desktop not installed:"
    echo "  * Install docker desktop from <https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/>"
fi
```

**Explaination**

- `--format '{{.OperatingSystem}}'` is a Go template which queries from `docker info`.
- `grep 'Docker Desktop'` is what you should be looking for if you're running Docker Desktop.
- `-z` returns true if the length of the string is 0 (from `man bash`).
- `$(...)` is command substitution which executes the `grep` without outputting to `stdout`.

Hat tip to [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6172107/joe-alamo) for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49257710/712334) which cleanly filters the output from `docker info`. And if you refactor to stop using Machine you can consider removing VirtualBox from your environment setup and leverage the performance gains of [`xhyve`](https://github.com/machyve/xhyve) – included with Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
docker info --format "{{.OperatingSystem}}" | grep -q "Docker for Mac"
```

Check the exit code via:

```
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "Docker for Mac!"
else
    echo "Something else"
fi
```

Comment: Use of `$?` [is an anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248031/meaning-of-dollar-question-mark-in-shell-scripts#comment92545215_27501200) and the `-q` is _clever_ which is adds complexity to debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version if it is installed or not. By that you will get whether it is installed or not on your machine.
Type this in your terminal.

`docker --version`