# what is the benefit of $? in bash

Tags: linux, bash, git-bash

I'm new in variable concept in bash and I have seen some courses how to use and when to use special variable like $# to see how many arguments were passed in bash script and $@ to see all the arguments supplied to the Bash script.

but I haven't understood $? and they just say that $? (The exit status of the most recently run process) and also I haven't got anything.

I need a little explanation and please give an example.

Comment: Pretty sure this forum has an answer for that already, Well as far as the shell is concern if the value of `$?` is zero that means it truth and else it is false. So example if the recent command succeeded which means the value of `$?` is zero one can act upon it, either execute another command or do something else.

Comment: Could please give an example even if it small

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248031/meaning-of-dollar-question-mark-in-shell-scripts does that answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of $? (dollar question mark) in shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248031/meaning-of-dollar-question-mark-in-shell-scripts)

Comment: @frankmark, I told you, this has already answers in this forum, just need to search first before posting a new question, and if you find that the post in that link is what you're looking for, please vote by clicking the arrow/triangle that is pointing up.

Comment: As you mentioned, it gives the exit status of the last executed command. You can check the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248031/meaning-of-dollar-question-mark-in-shell-scripts for detailed information with example. Also you can take a look at website below if you are new learner in bash programming.
https://devhints.io/bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That definition you gave, i.e. the exit status of the most recently run process, is exactly what is is; but if you don't get how processes and commands in general work on the command line, I can understand how that might be a bit confusing.

In general, any command you run on the command line will have an exit code. In something like C/C++, you might have seen it as the `return 0;` appended at the end of every `main()` routine, and in shell scripts you might have seen it as `exit 0`. These return codes are the primary way to signal to the external environment (in this case the terminal) that things either ended well, or they didn't.

This is where `$?` comes into play. The convention on Unix systems is to have a process return exit code `0` if everything went fine, and return a non-zero value if it didn't. So, let's say I wrote a simple main routine like so:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argv[1] == "true") {  // not quite right, but fine for examples
        return 0;
    }
    else if (argv[1] == "false") {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

If I run this in the commnand line as `./a.out true`, then this program will return 0 and the `$?` variable will be set to 0 as well. If I type `./a.out false`, however, the program will return 1 and `$?` will also be set to 1, which indicates that something went wrong.

This seems pretty redundant if you're just toying around in the command line, running commands and then `echo $?` to see the result, but this really becomes useful in Bash scripting, where you might want to see what the command you just ran returns. For example, the `diff` command returns 0 if the two files you specify don't differ, and 1 if they do. This gives a neat way to introduce some control flow into your program, but you **have to be careful**, because `$?` is set after *every* command you run.

I hope this helped!