# how to check if a word exists on a web page

Tags: bash, shell

In this example script below

```
keyword="google"
var1="wget -qO- https://www.google.com"
echo "$var1"
var2="[test -z "$var1 | grep $keyword"]"
echo $var2
```

I get

```
 wget -qO- https://www.google.com
```

but var2 is empty.

In this script

```
keyword="google"
var1="wget -qO- https://www.google.com"
echo " $var1"
var2="[test -z "https://www.google.com" | grep "google"]"
echo $var2
```

I get

```
wget -qO- https://www.google.com
[test -z https://www.google.com | grep google]
```

I've tried any number of permutations of single and double quotes but I cannot get the test statement to evaluate.

How can I actually get a test command to evaluate in a script?
And How can I use variables in a 'test' command?

Comment: See [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash) But in the case of a test expression (which starts with `[` or `test`, but not both, and has spaces between each element) it doesn't produce output, it produces an [exit status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248031/meaning-of-dollar-question-mark-in-shell-scripts). BTW, [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at pointing out common mistakes (although it doesn't catch all of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Variables

```sh
var2="[test -z "$var1 | grep $keyword"]"
```

Let's see what is and what is not quoted here:

- `"[test -z "` - first quoted atom, so far good
- `$var1` - variable gets expanded and concatenated to previous string
- `| grep $keyword` - first problem, there are no quotes where are whitespaces, Bash doesn't know what to do with it (it thinks those are arguments and tries to pipe variable assignation to `grep`)
- `"]"` - it appends it to `$keyword`, which is `grep` argument

So Bash first executes `var2="[test -z "$var1` then pipes it to `grep $keyword"]"`

Possible solutions:

- many quotes: `var2='[test -z '"$var1"' | grep '"$keyword"']'`
- one quotes: `var2="[test -z $var1 | grep $keyword]"`

This is in regards of variables.

### Evaluation

To evaluate text string as shell command (although you should avoid doing that at all), you simply use `eval` command:

```sh
eval "$var2"
```

or just variable alone:

```sh
"$var2"
```

### Actual problem, i.e. checking for a word

Evaluating `var2` makes no sense as the code contained inside is simply invalid. Making it a variable is needless at all.

You simply need to do:

```sh
keyword="google"
var1="wget -qO- https://www.google.com"

if test -z "$($var1 | grep $keyword)"; then
    echo "Not found word"
fi
```

Why was code in `var2` invalid:

- square brackets - `[` is an alias for `test`. Writing `[ test` is (almost) equivalent to `test test`. The difference between `test` and `[` is that in case of `[` you need to end command with `]`
- no spaces after `[` and before `]`
- when you want to use output of a command, you need to capture it using `$(command)`

Comment: thaank you so much, both of you. I felt like I had fallen through the looking glass and was in wonderland.