# Why is $? creating a file?

Tags: bash

In the following script I am testing how to count how many times a command runs.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello"
scount=$?
if [ $scount -eq 0 ]; then
    
    count=$(cat ${scount})
else
    count=0
fi
((count++))

echo ${count} > ${scount}
echo "Scount: $count"
```

This is the output I receive. I am confused as to why I am getting the `cat: 0: No such file or directory` message.

```
Hello
cat: 0: No such file or directory
Scount: 1
```

Comment: `I am confused as to why I am getting the cat: 0: No such file or directory message.` Because you're calling `cat ${scount}` with `scount` = `0`.

Comment: It's not creating a file, which is why there's no such file. What did you expect from `cat` given that you've just verified that scount is zero?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Are you aware of what `$?` means? And that a file needs to already exist if you supply it as an argument to `cat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said on Unix [manual for cat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html)

> cat - concatenate files and print on the standard output

And as said on $? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248031/meaning-of-dollar-question-mark-in-shell-scripts)

> $? is the exit status of the last executed command.

So:

- cat command wants a file to read and print in standard output
- $? is a number and its value is 0, cause the last command executed in that point of the script was `echo "Hello"` (well executed = status 0)

You're trying to do something like `cat 0` so with this:

```
count=$(cat ${scount})
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
        echo "Hello"
        scount=$?
        if [ $scount -eq 0 ]; then
            
            count=$(cat ${scount})
        else
            count=0
        fi
```

I think you were wanting to assign 0 to count and used `cat` instead of `echo`

```sh
count=$(echo "$scount")
```

But that's a useless use of echo

```sh
count=$scount
```

But now you're assigning 0 to count in both branches of the `if` statement, so you can remove the whole `if`:

```sh
        echo "Hello"
        scount=$?
        count=0
```