# How the value is assigned to the variable with shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have this code but I don't understand it very well.

Can you explain to me how the finish variable gets the value.

what does this assignment "finish=$?" mean?

or if they have any documentation to help me understand.

Thanks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

/usr/bin/java -jar Report.jar $user $pass $base $dateini $datefin $iphost >> file.log 2>&1

finish=$?

if [ $finish -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Report executed successfully" >> file.log
  exit 0
else
  echo "There was an error in the report" >> file.log
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: `$?` is the exit code of the previous command executed, in your case `java -jar ...`. Usually an exit code of 0 represents success while a different one represents an error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of $? (dollar question mark) in shell scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248031/meaning-of-dollar-question-mark-in-shell-scripts)

Comment: See [Why is testing "$?" to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36313216/4154375).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exit status of the last command you ran (`/usr/bin/java -jar ...`) is stored in the special parameter `$?`.

Commands executed by the shell script or user have a exit status being either 0 (meaning the command was successful without errors), or a non-zero (1-255) value indicating the command was a failure.

Check [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) for further information