# What does "$?" give us exactly in a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I saw the code written somewhere online, and I wanted to know what exactly does "$?" do/give us.
Googling did not help.

Here's the code I saw it in:

```
#!/bin/sh

ping -c 2 localhost
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
    echo "Couldn't ping localhost, weird"
    fi

ping -c 2 veryweirdhostname.noend 
if [ $? != 0 ] ; then
    echo "Surprise, Couldn't ping a very weird hostname.."
    fi

echo "The pid of this process is $$"
```

Taken from: http://efod.se/writings/linuxbook/html/shell-scripts.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90418/exit-shell-script-based-on-process-exit-code

It gives the exit status of the last executed command

Comment: $? is the return code from the last command

Comment: And as always, the use of `cmd; if [ $? != 0 ]; then stuff; fi` is an antipattern which is more elegantly and idiomatically written `if ! cmd ; then stuff; fi` (provided you do not need the value of `$?` in `stuff`, which which case `if cmd; then : nothing; else stuff with $?; fi`) or even `cmd || stuff`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`$?` is a variable holding the return value of the last command you ran.

Example C program (`example.c`):

```
int main() { return 1; }
```

Example Bash:

```
gcc -o example example.c
./example
echo $? # prints 1
```

Comment: But only if that return value is an 8-bit integer. See [Jens' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13823424/418413) and http://stackoverflow.com/a/2726480/418413 for more detail.

Answer (score 16):

Most of the answers are missing a bit of detail. A definitive answer is found in the [POSIX standard for the shell, in the section on special parameters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02):

> $?    Expands to the decimal exit status of the most recent pipeline
>   (see Pipelines ).

Don't be surprised by the word *pipeline*, because even a simple command such as `ls` is grammatically a pipeline consisting of a single command. But then, what is `$?` for a multi-command pipeline? It's the exit status of the *last* command in the pipeline.

And what about pipelines executing in the background, like `grep foo bigfile|head -n 10 > result &`?

Their exit status can be retrieved through `wait` once the pipeline's last command has finished.
The background process pid is available as `$!`, and `$?` only reports whether the background command was correctly *started*.

Another detail worth mentioning is that the exit status is usually in the range 0 through 255, with 128 to 255 indicating the process exited due to a signal. Returning other values from a C program is likely to not be reflected accurately in `$?`.

Comment: +1 This is a great, comprehensive answer. The only thing I would say is in the last sentence it's pretty clear what will happen when a C program returns a value besides 0-255: `$?` will be the low-order 8 bits of the implicit integer cast of the return value. While few programs are silly enough to exit with a double or a char, several rely on this modulo-256 behavior when they return negative values.

Comment: (On the other hand, when invoking the `exit` command in a POSIX shell, giving it an argument other than 0-255 [is undefined](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_21_03).)

Comment: @kojiro What's an *implicit cast*? Casts are always explicit in C. Did you perhaps mean *arithmetic conversion* or *masking*?

Comment: Yes, I abused the word *cast*. I meant *implicit conversion*.

Answer (score 8):

It's the return code from the most recently executed command.

By convention 0 is a successful exit and non-zero indicates some kind of error.

Answer (score 1):

This special variable shows the exit status of the last command that was run in a script or command-line. For example, in a command-line, the user could type

```
 who; echo $?
```

The output would then be

```
 user  tty7         2014-07-13 19:47
 0
```

This shows the output of *who* and the exit status of the command. A script would be the same.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 who
 echo $?
```

Output: 0

Answer (score 0):

the other answers cover bash pretty well, but you don't specify a shell in your question. In csh (and tcsh) `$?` can be used to [query the existence of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336388/csh-idioms-to-check-for-environment-variable-existence), e.g.

```
if $?my_var then
    echo my_var exists
endif
```