# What does '$?' mean in bash scripts?

Tags: bash, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “$?” give us exactly in a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383144/what-does-give-us-exactly-in-a-shell-script)

What does `$?` mean in a bash script? Example below:

```
#!/bin/bash
# userlist.sh

PASSWORD_FILE=/etc/passwd
n=1           # User number

for name in $(awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{print $1}' < "$PASSWORD_FILE" )

do
  echo "USER #$n = $name"
  let "n += 1"
done

exit $?
```

Comment: The return value/exit status of the most recently executed command.

Comment: Ah sorry for the duplicate. "$?" is hard to search for.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$?
```

is the last error (or success) returned:

```
$?
1: command not found.
echo $?
127

false 
echo $?
1

true 
echo $?
0
```

The exit in the end:

```
exit $?
```

is superfluous, because the bash script will exit with that status anyway. Citing the man page:

> Bash's exit status is the exit status of the last command  executed  in the  script.

Comment: Thanks for adding that the exit $? is superfluous.