# How to build a conditional assignment in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm looking a way to build conditional assignments in bash:

In Java it looks like this:

```
int variable= (condition) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: In case the condition involves `test`, `[[`  or `[` see [this question](/q/24896433)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

As per Jonathan's comment:

```
variable=$(( 1 == 1 ? 1 : 0 ))
```

#### EDIT:

I revised the original answer which just `echo`'d the value of the condition operator, it didn't actually show any *assignment.*

Comment: Nit-pick: that isn't an assignment - it is just a conditional expression.  However, `variable=$(( 1 == 1 ? 1 : 0 ))` works as long as there are no spaces around the first '=' sign; you can omit all the spaces after that and it also works - but think about readability.

Comment: You can have complete freedom of spacing (and drop the dollar sign) if you move the opening double parentheses all the way to the left. `(( variable = 1 == 1 ? 1 : 0 ))` or `(( variable = (1 == 1) ? 1 : 0 ))` But it could be argued that it's more readable as given in the answer.

Comment: Also, it should be noted that this operator only works for arithmetic operations in Bash.

Comment: What if the variable I want to set is a string?

Comment: This does not work for strings: echo $(( 1 == 1 ? 'hello' : 'world' ))

Answer (score 90):

If you want a way to define defaults in a shell script, use code like this:

```
: ${VAR:="default"}
```

Yes, the line begins with ':'. I use this in shell scripts so I can override variables in ENV, or use the default.

This is related because this is my most common use case for that kind of logic. ;]

Comment: This is a valuable technique, but the only condition supported with the ':=' notation is 'set to "default" if value is unset or empty'.  The more general notation in the question is supported directly in bash.

Comment: I agree completely, I gave it a disclaimer for being slightly off topic.

Comment: Omitting the colon before equal tests only for the variable to be unset and doesn't change it if it's null.

Comment: Related useful explanation about starting with a colon and the parameter expansion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307735/1180551).

Comment: This will not work if you're trying to assign default value to a parameter of a function. E.g. `${2:="some value"}` will fail.

Answer (score 51):

I wanted to do a conditional assignment with strings and I ended up with:

```bash
VAR=$([ "$MYVALUE" = "value" ] && echo "YES" || echo "NO")
```

Which is:

```bash
VAR=$([ condition ] && value_when_true || value_when_false)
```

Comment: one line beauty!

Comment: This results in nothing be assigned to the variables?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell You can it assigns if you run it and `echo $VAR`

Answer (score 50):

```
myvar="default" && [[ <some_condition_is_true> ]]  && myvar="non-default"
```

real examples:

```
DELIM="" && [[ "$APP_ENV_RESOLVED" != "" ]] && DELIM=$INNER_DELIM
```

The condition can be "(( ... ))" as well:

```
filepath=/proc/drbd && (( $# > 0 )) && filepath=$1
```

Answer (score 38):

In addition to the other more general answers (particularly as per Jonathan's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440947/how-to-build-a-conditional-assignment-in-bash#comment2426872_2440950) and Kevin's [more general answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2441287/3102305) [which also supports strings]) I'd like to add the following two solutions:

## setting the variable to either `0` or `1` based on the condition:

(as the question's example suggests.)

The general form would read

```
(condition); variable=$?;
```

where `$variable` results in being either `0` or `1` and `condition` can be any valid [conditional expression](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions).

E.g. checking a variable ...

```
[[ $variableToCheck == "$othervariable, string or number to match" ]]
variable=$?
```

... or checking a file's existence ...

```
[ -f "$filepath" ]
fileExists=$?
```

... or checking the nummerical value of `$myNumber`:

```
(( myNumber >= 1000000000 ))
is_huge_number=$?
```

#### The advantages of this solution is that

- it supports **arbitrary [conditional expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions), including strings**
  (which are not supported in [arithmetic expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic) of Jonathan's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440947/how-to-build-a-conditional-assignment-in-bash#comment2426872_2440950))
- that **`variable` gets declared** in any case, unlike in griffon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23405016/3102305):
  `[ -z "$variable" ] && variable="defaultValue"`
  Which would matter in case you want to [nameref](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters) it later on (e.g. from within a function).

**Please note:** In Bash, the special variable `$?` always contains the exit code of the previously executed statement (or statement block; see the [man bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) for more details). As such, a positive result is generally represented by the value `0`, not `1` (See my comment [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440947/how-to-build-a-conditional-assignment-in-bash/35890017#comment66299538_35890017), thanks Assimilater for [pointing it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440947/how-to-build-a-conditional-assignment-in-bash/35890017#comment66247340_35890017)). Thus, if the condition is true (e.g `[[2 eq 2]]`) then `$?=0`.

If instead you need 0 or 1 in your variable (e.g. to print or do mathematical calculations) then you need to employ boolean negation using a leading exclamation mark (as pointed out by GypsySpellweaver in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440947/how-to-build-a-conditional-assignment-in-bash/35890017#comment96418436_35890017) below): `( ! condition ); variable=$?` or `! ( condition ); variable=$?`. (However, readability in terms of what happens might be a bit less obvious.)

Another possible [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440947/how-to-build-a-conditional-assignment-in-bash#comment2426872_2440950) by Jonathan would be `variable=$(( 1 == 1 ? 1 : 0 ))` - which, however, is creating a subshell.

If you want to avoid the creation of a subshel, keep good readability or  have arbitrary conditions, use one of the following solutions.

## setting the variable to arbitrary values:

as it is done in most other answers, it could adapted as follows:

```
(condition) \
    && variable=true \
    || variable=false
```

e.g as in

```
[[ $variableToCheck == "$othervariable, string or number to match" ]] \
    && variable="$valueIfTrue" \
    || variable="$valueIfFalse"
```

or to get 1 in a positive check, and 0 upon failure (like in the question's example):

```
[[ $variableToCheck == "$othervariable, string or number to match" ]] \
    && variable=1 \
    || variable=0
```

(for the last example, - as already mentioned in the notes above - the same can be achieved with boolean negation using a leading exclamation mark:

```
[[ ! $variableToCheck == "$othervariable, string or number to match" ]]
variable=$?
```

#### The advantages of this solution is that

- it might be considered a bit **better readable** than Kevin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2441287/3102305)
  `myvar="default" && [[ <some_condition_is_true> ]]  && myvar="non-default"`, and
- the **`$valueIfTrue` is conditionally evaluated *only* if needed**,
  which would matter in case you'd do something

  - with side-effect, like

    - `variable=$((i++))`, or
    - `{ variable=$1; shift; }`
  - high computation, like

    - `variable=$(find / -type f -name ListOfFilesWithThisNameOnMySystem)`
- is a bit **shorter** than ghostdog74's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2441183/3102305)
  (which, however is great if you have multiple conditions!)
- does not open a subshell as in Pierre's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35065114/3102305)
- and as above:

  - it supports **arbitrary [conditional expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions), including strings**
    (which are not supported in [arithmetic expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic) of Jonathan's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440947/how-to-build-a-conditional-assignment-in-bash#comment2426872_2440950))
  - that **`variable` gets declared** in any case, unlike in griffon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23405016/3102305):
    `[ -z "$variable" ] && variable="defaultValue"`
    Which would matter in case you want to [nameref](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters) it later on (e.g. from within a function).

Comment: The result of your first solution is a little confusing to me. A conditional that evaluates to true results in a value of 0; where a conditional that evaluates to false results in a value of 1

Comment: Maybe I did it wrong though. I test with `[ "$1" == "--all" ] ; 
allperiods=$? ; 
echo $allperiods`

Comment: @Assimilater, I agree, that 0 and 1 might be confusing. It stems from the fact that an exit code of a program or statement is usually 0 when everything went ok, and an arbitrary code (usually between 1 and 254) for errors. Thus `executable && executesWhenOk || executesWhenNotOk` and in our scenario the test is the "executable" (or statement, to be precise), and the special variable `$?` contains the result code of the last statement. hope that helps clarifying.

Comment: That helps :) (You might consider adding it to the answer ;) )

Comment: This is the best solution, especially as the accepted answer only works for arithmetic expressions. It is also more readable @kevin's and shorter than the verbose, but otherwise excellent and more-general `case` solution by @ghostdog74.

Comment: The "normal" Boolean logic which programmers are adapted to, of `1` is `true` and `0` is `false`, can easily be achieved in this case with the _NOT_ `!` operator applied to the expression. Either inside, or outside the 'expression'. `( ! condition ); variable=$?` or `! ( condition ); variable=$?` Such that `[ ! -f "$filepath" ]; fileExists=$?` works as a programmer would be accustomed to: 1 file exists, and 0 file is missing.

Comment: HI @GypsySpellweaver, thanks for your comment. Yes, sure, that's a possibility. However, be aware that if later you use `$fileExists` in a further test, you have to negate it again every single time.

Comment: Agree. That's why I mentioned, do it only if you need it for e.g. mathematical calculations. - I have added your solution to the post. Needs to be moderated before it will appear though. Thanks again!

Comment: If I use this with 2 assignments, it behaves oddly. `[[ some condition ]] && IS_IDENTITY=0 || IS_IDENTITY=1
[[ some other condition ]] && IS_CORE=0 || IS_CORE=1` If the first condition is true and the 2nd false, `IS_CORE` will always be set to 1, and `IS_IDENTITY` will be 0

Comment: @DouglasGaskell, if I understand you correctly, `IS__IDENTITY`should be set based on the evaluation of `[[ some condition ]]`, while `IS_CORE` should be set based on `[[ some other condition ]]`. In that case, you need to add a semicolon `;` between the two statements (i.e. `[[ some condition ]] && IS_IDENTITY=0 || IS_IDENTITY=1; [[ some other condition ]] && IS_CORE=0 || IS_CORE=1`) or put them on two separate lines! Without that, the `IS_CORE=1` is called after a positive `some condition` *and* positive setting of `IS_IDENTITY=0` (which yields true). The code fails if `some condition` =false

Comment: [Why is testing `$?` to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern) This is tangential here, but I can't help but think `condition && var=yes || var=no` is so much more readable and idiomatic than this solution.

Answer (score 14):

**Big ups** to @Demosthenex and especially @Dennis Williamson for the *shortest and easiest* solution I've seen. *Leave it to bash* to require a bunch of *parentheses* for a simple ternary assignment. *Ahh, the 60s*!  And to put it all together in an example...

```
echo $BASHRULES;             # not defined
                             # no output
: ${BASHRULES:="SCHOOL"}     # assign the variable
echo $BASHRULES              # check it
SCHOOL                       # correct answer
: ${BASHRULES="FOREVER?"}    # notice the slightly different syntax for the conditional assignment
echo $BASHRULES              # let's see what happened!
SCHOOL                       # unchanged! (it was already defined)
```

I wrote that a long time ago.. these days I'd probably get more excited over a solution like...

```
PLATFORM=iphonesimulator
OTHERSDK=iphone && [[ $PLATFORM=~os ]]      \
                &&     OTHERSDK+=simulator  \
                ||     OTHERSDK+=os
```

> `$OTHERSDK` ⇥ `iphoneos`

Comment: Thank you, Mr. @alex gray. This is an excellent syntactic arrow that everyone should have in their `bash` quiver… for the curious and/or unadventurous who discover it here, this sort of conditional assignment plays nice with `export` statements, too – which you put that between the colon prefix and the dollar-sign statement-y part, e.g. `: export ${YO_DOGG:="global environment default"}`

Comment: Your second solution, actually represents the second solution of my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35890017/3102305) and was added only [after](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15182923/revisions) I've posted it. A short reference would have been nice. Please also note, since `iphonesimulator` does not contain the string `os`, above solution would end up with `OTHERSDK=iphonesimulator`.

Comment: I like this short answer. Some of the others were too long.

Comment: The Bourne shell was created in the late 1970s, and Bash in the late 1980s.

Answer (score 6):

another way using a case/switch

```
case "$variable" in
  condition) result=1 ;;
          *) result=0 ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to assign a value unless variable is empty use this:

```
[ -z "$variable" ] && variable="defaultValue"
```

You can put as well, each other condition on the `[]`

Comment: Variable expansion is meant to handle this as follow `: ${variable:='defaultValue'}`