# Bash conditional assignment that tests a variable whilst building a string

Tags: bash, string-concatenation, conditional-operator

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440947/how-to-build-a-conditional-assignment-in-bash) for how to do conditional assignment in bash, but what I'm trying to do is a little more complex, and I can't seem to get the syntax right. The condition in my case is to test a variable to see if it exists, and the output is concatenated to a string.

Here's what I have so far:

```
fwversion="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.$(( [[ BASH_REMATCH[2] ]] ? BASH_REMATCH[2] : 0 ))"
```

Which produces this error message:

```
bash: line 41: [[ BASH_REMATCH[2] ]] ? BASH_REMATCH[2] : 0 : syntax error: 
operand expected (error token is "[[ BASH_REMATCH[2] ]] ? BASH_REMATCH[2] : 0 ")
```

Here's what I'm trying to achieve as C++ code:

```
std::string fwversion = BASH_REMATCH[1] + "." + ((BASH_REMATCH[2]) ? : BASH_REMATCH[2] : 0);
```

What's the correct syntax to do this in bash? Thanks.

Comment: That's actually C++ code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `[[ ... ]]` are not understood in an arithmetic expression.

I'd do this:

```
fwversion=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
[[ ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ]] && fwversion+=${BASH_REMATCH[2]} || fwversion+=0
```

or

```
[[ ${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ]] && ext=${BASH_REMATCH[2]} || ext=0
fwversion="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.$ext"
```

---

On second thought, I wouldn't do that at all, I'd use the power of the shell's [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

```
str="foo:bar"
if [[ $str =~ ^([a-z]+):([a-z]*)$ ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.${BASH_REMATCH[2]:-0}"
fi
```

```
foo.bar
```

```
str="foo:"
if [[ $str =~ ^([a-z]+):([a-z]*)$ ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.${BASH_REMATCH[2]:-0}"
fi
```

```
foo.0
```

Comment: Hmmm, makes sense, although not very readable. honestly I'm tempted to do it with if then else statements.

Comment: Well that looks a lot nicer. Is there a reference for that :- construct?

Comment: In the link I provided in the answer