# variable expansion in curly braces

Tags: bash

This is code

```
a=''
b=john
c=${a-$b}
echo $c
```

And the output is empty line

And for similar code where first variable is not initialized

```
b1=doe
c1=${a1-$b1}
echo $c1
```

And the output is

```
doe
```

I do not understand how bash deals with expanding of variables leading to different results.

Answer (score 63):

There are two variants of the `${var-value}` notation, one without a colon, as shown, and one with a colon: `${var:-value}`.

The first version, without colon, means 'if `$var` is set to any value (including an empty string), use it; otherwise, use `value` instead'.

The second version, with colon, means 'if `$var` is set to any value except the empty string, use it; otherwise, use `value` instead'.

This pattern holds for other variable substitutions too, notably:

- `${var:=value}`

  - if `$var` is set to any non-empty string, leave it unchanged; otherwise, set `$var` to `value`.
- `${var=value}`

  - if `$var` is set to any value (including an empty string), leave it unchanged; otherwise, set `$var` to `value`.
- `${var:?message}`

  - if `$var` is set to any non-empty string, do nothing; otherwise, complain using the given message' (where a default message is supplied if `message` is itself empty).
- `${var?message}`

  - if `$var` is set to any value (including an empty string), do nothing; otherwise, complain using the given message'.

These notations all apply to any POSIX-compatible shell (Bourne, Korn, Bash, and others).  You can find the manual for the `bash` version online — in the section [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).  Bash also has a number of non-standard notations, many of which are extremely useful but not necessarily shared with other shells.

Comment: What does the `+` mean as shown in `if test "${var+set}" = set; then` at [How can I check an environment variable?](http://gnu-autoconf.7623.n7.nabble.com/How-can-I-check-an-environment-variable-td13092.html)

Comment: `${var+set}` expands to `set` if `$var` is defined (even if it is defined but empty), whereas `${var:+set}` expands to `set` if `$var` is defined and the value is not the empty string.  Both expand to nothing if the variable is not set at all.  Read the Bash manual on [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for more details and more substitutions.  See also [What's a concise way to check that environment variables are set in a Unix shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307503/what/307735#307735)