# Checking for environment variable

Tags: unix

Using this UNIX script I am able to check if variable TEST_VAR is set or not:

```
: ${TEST_VAR:?"Not set or empty."}
```

I am new to unix so can someone please explain what is this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`bash`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) manual:

> ```
> ${parameter:?word}
> ```
>
> If parameter is null or unset, the expansion of word (or a message to
>   that effect if word is not present) is written to the standard error
>   and the shell, if it is not interactive, exits. Otherwise, the value
>   of parameter is substituted.

Answer (score 1):

It is the original shell comment notation (before '#' to end of line). For a long time, Bourne shell scripts had a colon as the first character. The C Shell would read a script and use the first character to determine whether it was for the C Shell (a '#' hash) or the Bourne shell (a ':' colon). Then the kernel got in on the act and added support for '#!/path/to/program' and the Bourne shell got '#' comments, and the colon convention went by the wayside

Have a look at this similar question:

[What's a concise way to check that environment variables are set in a Unix shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307503/whats-the-best-way-to-check-that-environment-variables-are-set-in-unix-shellscr)

Comment: you're mistaken. In the poster's example, it is simply the ":" command (whih on most shell act as a "nop" command, but you can have it preceded/followed by things, such as here: it is followed by a ${parameter:?word} construct. So it is "(do nothing) ${TEST_VAR:?"Not set or empty."}  : it will then just "test" if TESTVAR exists, and exit with the error message (on stderr) if not. Actually you're not really mistaken : the ":" command is probably a descendant of that thing you mentionned, and exist also for compatibility reasons.