# Linux environment variables behavior

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, centos, redhat

How does env variables work on bash when they are not set, in the example below, I wanted to delete a linux directory that i thought i have already set before but because i didn't set the variables, the operation is going to be executed on everything, i'd like some help to understand how does it work ? and how i can avoid that ?

```
     ubuntu@osn:~$ sudo rm -rf $I_HOME/$I_VERSION/
     rm: it is dangerous to operate recursively on ‘//’ (same as ‘/’)
     rm: use --no-preserve-root to override this failsafe
```

Comment: Related: [What's a concise way to check that environment variables are set in Unix shellscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307503/whats-a-concise-way-to-check-that-environment-variables-are-set-in-unix-shellsc). You can just type `set -u` if you'd like it to always check for unset vars.

Comment: `set -u` will always check for unset variables. If you only need those 2 variables checked you can use `rm -rf ${I_HOME:?Please set the value}/${I_VERSION:?What version is it again}/`.

Answer (score 0):

as you have not set the variables they're default value is '' so your statement becomes:

```
sudo rm -rf //
```

when you say this:

```
SOMEVAR="someValue"
```

it creates and sets the env variable for the current bash process.
to set the variable for all processes created by bash you can write this:

```
export SOMEVAR="someValue"
```

you can also add the variable to all future bash processes by adding this line to your .bashrc file.