# How to test if env variable is set in bats-assert framework?

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, bats-core

I am using BATS testing framework with bats-assert and bats-support.

I want to ensure that the user remembered to set the ELASTIC_CREDS env variable properly.  How do I do that?   Here is what I've tried:

```
config.bash
export SYSTEM_CREDS=myuser:mypass
```

Then, my checkcreds.bats test fike looks like this:

```
checkcreds.bats
#! ./libs/bats/bin/bats
load 'libs/bats-support/load'
load 'libs/bats-assert/load'
load 'config'

@test 'assert_system_creds()' {
  run env | grep SYSTEM_CREDS | awk -F= '{print$2}'
  assert_output --regexp '^.*:.*$'
}
```

Comment: See [What's a concise way to check that environment variables are set in a Unix shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307503/whats-a-concise-way-to-check-that-environment-variables-are-set-in-a-unix-shell)  I believe this could/should be a duplicate of that.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in Bash, or in Bats?

Comment: `grep 'x' | awk '{ y }'` can usefully be refactored to `awk '/x/ { y }'`; see also [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Comment: I'd like to know how to do that concisely using Bats, but the link that J.Leffler posted is very helpful and may just be what I need.

Answer (score 4):

This expression works fine:

```
@test 'check_env_vars()' { 
  run : ${SYSTEM_CREDS?"Need to set SYSTEM_CREDS"} 
  assert_success 
}
```